# Is it possible to loop through the Data Worksheet?

Tags: vba, excel

I was wondering if there was a way to loop through my Data worksheet, rather than coding it out from A2 to AQ2?

```
Worksheets("FORM TEMPLATE").Range("D9").Copy
Worksheets("Data").Range("A2").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

Worksheets("FORM TEMPLATE").Range("D10").Copy
Worksheets("Data").Range("B2").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

Worksheets("FORM TEMPLATE").Range("J9").Copy
Worksheets("Data").Range("C2").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

Worksheets("FORM TEMPLATE").Range("J10").Copy
Worksheets("Data").Range("D2").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

Worksheets("FORM TEMPLATE").Range("J11").Copy
Worksheets("Data").Range("E2").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
```

Comment: While your target is contiguous (`A2:AQ2`), your source is not and there does not appear to be a mathematical pattern from what little you've shown. You might try `Worksheets("Data").Range("XFD2").End(xlToLeft).Offset(0, 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues` but only after the first one is pasted into A2.

Comment: That;s a lot of cli[board action. Have you considered putting it into an array and bulk dumping the array of values into the data worksheet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Create an array to hold the data
- Resize the array to match the number of cells in the range
- Loop the cells in the range
- Increment the counter
- Add the value of the current cell to the array
- Size the destination range to fit the data and assign the array to this range

---

```
Sub LoopData()
    Dim Data()
    Dim x As Long
    Dim c As Range

    With Worksheets("FORM TEMPLATE").Range("D9,D10,J9:J11")
        ReDim Data(1 To .Cells.Count)

        For Each c In .Cells
            x = x + 1
            Data(x) = c.Value
        Next
        Worksheets("Data").Range("B2").Resize(1, UBound(Data)) = Data
    End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

Load the values into an array and assign values to the array. After loading the array in an orderly fashion, dump it all back onto the Data worksheet at once.

```
Sub wqewtry()
    Dim a As Long, arr As Variant

    'preload and shape the array
    With Worksheets("Data")
        arr = .Range("A2:AQ2").Value2
    End With

    With Worksheets("FORM TEMPLATE")
        'use .Value2 for text or numbers; .Value for dates
        a = a + 1: arr(1, a) = .Range("D9").Value2
        a = a + 1: arr(1, a) = .Range("D10").Value2
        a = a + 1: arr(1, a) = .Range("J9").Value2
        a = a + 1: arr(1, a) = .Range("J10").Value2
        a = a + 1: arr(1, a) = .Range("J11").Value2
    End With

    'dump back into the data worksheet
    With Worksheets("Data")
        .Range("A2:AQ2") = arr
    End With

End Sub
```

This should make it easier to write the code while keeping it organized and making it faster.

Comment: Seems the two `With Worksheets("Data")` blocks aren't buying you anything really; the reference is acquired and dereferenced twice - IMO a better solution would be to either nest the `With` blocks or keep a local `Worksheet` variable for the "Data" sheet; an even better solution would refer to worksheets by their *code name*, using the already-existing global objects we get for free, e.g. `DataSheet.Range(...)`.

Comment: Fair enough. I try to proselytize the [With ... End With statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wc500chb.aspx) and [.Parent](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa224980.aspx) worksheet property as much as I can but I will admit that occasionally I go overboard.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. The following may not be the best code, but it seems your source cells are not contiguously loopable...

```
Dim SomeArray(X) As String      'Define "X" suitably for your input cells

SomeArray(0) = "D9"
SomeArray(1) = "D10"
SomeArray(2) = "J9"
SomeArray(3) = "J10"
etc...
```

Then you loop over the source cells array and copy each one:

```
curOffset=0
For i = LBound(SomeArray) To UBound(SomeArray)
    Worksheets("FORM TEMPLATE").Range(SomeArray(i)).Copy
    Worksheets("Data").Range("A2").Offset(0,curOffset).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    curOffset = curOffset + 1
Next i
```

Comment: I'd suggest grabbing a reference to the source and target sheets *before* starting the loop for more efficiency.

Comment: Why not write the values into `SomeArray` using the cell addresses in `SomeArray` then dump `SomeArray` back onto the worksheet with a transpose?

Answer (score 0):

As JetSetJim said - your source cells aren't easily identified.

```
Sub Test()

    Dim rToCopy As Range
    Dim rCell As Range
    Dim lColNum As Long

    lColNum = 1
    With ThisWorkbook
        Set rToCopy = .Worksheets("FORM TEMPLATE").Range("D9:D10,J9:J11")
        With .Worksheets("Data")
            For Each rCell In rToCopy
                .Cells(2, lColNum) = rCell.Value
                lColNum = lColNum + 1
            Next rCell
        End With
    End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

A method I like to use when working with a random set of values that can't be automatically determined is to create an array from a constant. In your case, something like:

```
Const csSource as string = "D9|D10|J9|J10|J11"

Dim varSource as Variant, i as integer
Dim rngTarget as range

varsource = split(cssource,"|")
set rngTarget = worksheets("Data").range("A2")

for i = 0 to ubound(varSource)
    rngtarget.value = worksheets("Form Template").range(varsource(i)).value
    set rngTarget = rngTarget.offset(0, 1)
next i
```

You can add new source values in the constant at the top as needed. This is a little more memory heavy than other methods, since it uses variants, but it's a lot easier to code and maintain.

Comment: `Option Base 1` would introduce a bug here. Best practice is to never assume what the lower bound of a dynamic array might be; `For i = LBound(varSource) To UBound(varSource)`. Also, you could skip the string variable and `Split` processing by simply inlining the array declaration with `varSource = Array("D9","D10","J9","J10","J11")`, and lastly calling `Worksheets("SheetName")` in a loop makes quite a lot of overhead for little reason (get the sheet object *before* you start looping)... and I'll argue that `.Offset` makes everything *harder* to maintain and reason about.

Comment: Actually, exactly what is `Set rngSource = rngSource.Offset(0, 1)` accomplishing? `rngSource` isn't used anywhere in your loop. It's also undeclared.

Comment: Good point - should've been rngTarget, not rngsource. My mistake